# Procedure or function 'sp_InsertImages' expects parameter '@Img_path', which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures

i have passed img_path in my code nd procedure but it show me error please anyone help me.
my procedure is :

```
create proc sp_InsertImages
(
  @Img_path nvarchar(max),
  @product_id numeric(18,0),
  @IsCover_Img bit
)
as
begin
if(select COUNT(*) from tbl_productImg where product_id=@product_id)<5
begin
insert into tbl_productImg(Img_path,product_id,IsCover_Img)values(@Img_path,@product_id,@IsCover_Img)
select @@IDENTITY
end
else
begin
select -1
end
end
```

[image]

Comment: I'm just going to assume the variable `Img_path` is `NULL`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Your Command Type must be set to `StoredProcedure` like this

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

To get the Product ID from the Procedure, call `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` like below

```
 product_ID = Convert.ToDouble(sql.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: @vibha, the `sp_` stored procedure prefix is reserved for system stored procedures.  In addition to renaming the proc, I suggest you add the appropriate schema name too (e.g. dbo) as this can improve performance.